# Date vs Names graph with highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to draw a graph between  dates and names. The graph which I need is in below format:
in below graph the data will be like
one column with dates and another with names...the names should be given different colors and on the same day if the name repeats it should be shown. i tried doing this, but not succeeded, please help me to draw this.

sryy it's not allowing to add image.

Comment: Could you attach any mockup of your goal?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I am unable to attach any files here.

Comment: Unfortunatley without any code / demo which introduce your issue, we have no chance to debug it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not allowing me to attach any images here. Will be there any email address where I can send the sample graph I am expecting.

Comment: Contact with us by support@highcharts.com